# html5 problem renders in ie8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, html

i got this issue with html5 in ie8 (i know its not supported), i use HTML5 Shiv and DOCTYPE html

I got the issue that it will work when the page renders but when i do a ajax request and load (in my case) a product it will ignore the html tags `<figure>` and `<section>`

anybody got an idea why its like this? i try to find a solutions and html5 shiv and doctype was pretty much what i found.. im ok with a jquery solution if there is any.. any ideas?

im not sure if my markup will help any in this case but ill show it anyway

```
<figure>
        <%= Html.ProductImageLinksThickbox("2", "1")%>
</figure>
```

this is the html that the browser renders

```
<figure/>
</figure/>
```

Comment: why not use a json and then create it that way.

Comment: http://www.winningwebworks.com/html5-correct-usage-is-this-code-correct-stack-overflow/ hope this helps in some way or maybe it will lead you to a better understanding... just read it briefly

Comment: because i am working on 2 large scale projects at a company and we can not change our structure in codes right now its to much work for little effort, i rather change the html then.

Comment: wait a second, whats with the extra `/` on the end of the tag? are you sure you are closing the tags properly ?

Comment: thats the ie8 that generates it, its dims it aswell and its not "active". i got my markup right here

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might not work, but worth a try.
json response:

```
r = {figure: 'bllalala'}// response as a json format that returns anything u wish as suppose to raw html.

$.ajax({
....
  success: function(r){
      $('#result').append($('<figure></figure>').html(r.figure))
  }
....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

my situation was so complex it was easier to change the html markup instead

**EDIT**

using this link that Alohci provided http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/ can solve this problem using jquery to get elements that need to be html5, after the your parialview have rendered. i will update with code when i get the time and hope this is clear with i mean.

Comment: S why do you write your own answer? when alohci had this answer and then accept yours as the best answer?

Comment: because it needs modifications for this situation, i just havent got around doing this code yet but its down the pipline. but when i post the code it its gone be the right answer and people gone relate more to the full solution.. and if you read the thing and watch the code provided in the link you will se its not what i ask for but its almost there, read the full thing. but i dont care i can change it

Comment: you can simply add to his answer :) below and bold it as update :)